# Awk or cut how to output the count of one unique column and other column values

Tags: linux, bash

Right now I have

```
grep "\sinstalled" combined_dpkg.log | awk -F ' ' '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
grep "\sinstalled" combined_dpkg.log | sort -k1 | awk '!a[$5]++' | cut -d " " -f1,5,6
```

And would like to combine the two into one query that includes the count of $5 with -f1,5,6.
If there is such a way to do so, or a way to retain values to be outputted following the final pipe.

The head -3 result of the first bash command above:

```
 11 man-db:amd64
 10 libc-bin:amd64
  9 mime-support:all
```

And of the second bash command:

```
2015-11-10 linux-headers-4.2.0-18-generic:amd64 4.2.0-18.22
2015-11-10 linux-headers-4.2.0-18:all 4.2.0-18.22
2015-11-10 linux-signed-image-4.2.0-18-generic:amd64 4.2.0-18.22
```

File format looks like:

```
2015-11-05 13:23:53 upgrade firefox:amd64 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu1 42.0+build2-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
2015-11-05 13:23:53 status half-configured firefox:amd64 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu1
2015-11-05 13:23:53 status unpacked firefox:amd64 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu1
2015-11-05 13:23:53 status half-installed firefox:amd64 41.0.2+build2-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Please mention your sample Input and expected output in code tags, sp that we could help you in same, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "\sinstalled" combined_dpkg.log | sort -k1 | awk '!a[$5]' | cut -d " " -f1,5,6 | uniq -c
```

Comment: "For each package find the earliest (first) version ever installed. Print the package name, the version and the total number of times it was installed." I need to apply the uniq to only one column but do not know how to do so

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment : *"For each package find the earliest (first) version ever installed. Print the package name, the version and the total number of times it was installed."*

I guess this **awk** would do.

```
awk '$0!~/ installed/{next} !($5 in a){a[$5]=$1 FS $5 FS $6; count[$5]++; next} count[$5]>0 && a[$5]~$6{count[$5]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i],count[i]}' file
```